# Zend Form Decorators for bootstrap twitter form

Tags: zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap

Can you detail how to setup the form decorators to end up with the following html? I'm not very good with the form decorators.

[twitterbootstrapform](http://pastebin.com/rDEgPcee)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here:
Zend_Form decorators for Twitter's Bootstrap

https://github.com/Emagister/zend-form-decorators-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you are a real Zend Form lover it should be possible to create a nice decorator that will give you the desired results. A easier solution, especially if you're not that good with Zend Form decorators, you could use a viewScript. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript